# In wx Python how do you kill a dialog on a mac?

Tags: python, macos

I have a simple dialog that works perfectly on Windows and Linux. However on a Mac it hangs when Self.Destroy() is called. It works perfectly if the control box is used, but I need to perform other tasks when a specific button is pressed

```
import wx
import Tabs as tabs

ID_TOOLS_tabs=wx.NewId()

class Example(wx.Frame):

  def __init__(self, parent, title):
    super(Example, self).__init__(parent, title=title, 
        size=(250, 200))

    menubar=wx.MenuBar()
    toolm=wx.Menu()
    menubar.Append(toolm, 'Tools')
    mitabs=wx.MenuItem(toolm, ID_TOOLS_tabs, 'Tabs')
    toolm.AppendItem(mitabs)
    self.SetMenuBar(menubar)

    self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.dlgTabs, id=ID_TOOLS_tabs)

    self.lblTest=wx.StaticText(self, label='waiting for ...')
    self.Center()
    self.Show()

  def dlgTabs(self, e):
    tabsScreen=tabs.TabScreen(None, title='')
    tabsScreen.ShowModal()
    self.lblTest.SetLabel('... Godo')
    tabsScreen.Destroy()


if __name__ == '__main__':

  myApp = wx.App()
  Example(None, title='Main screen')
  myApp.MainLoop()
```

and the dialog

```
import wx

class TabScreen(wx.Dialog):

  def __init__(self, parent, title):
    super(TabScreen, self).__init__(parent, title=title, 
        size=(250, 200))

    cmdCancel=wx.Button(self, label='Cancel')
    cmdCancel.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnClose)

    sizerMain=wx.GridBagSizer()

    sizerMain.Add(cmdCancel, pos=(2, 2), flag=wx.TOP|wx.LEFT|wx.RIGHT|wx.ALIGN_RIGHT, border=10)

    self.SetSizer(sizerMain)
    self.SetSize((250, 260))
    self.Center()
    self.Show()

  def OnClose(self, e):
    self.Destroy()
```

Any help appreciated

Comment: can the caller not call destroy ? and you just call `self.close()`

Comment: Thanks Joran - That does it